# Is this a known memory leak pattern in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, design-patterns

I'm working on a project and I'm experiencing memory leaks, I didn't find a way to figure out these leaks with node-inspector and v8-profiler modules. So I'm wondering if it exists known patterns that conduct to memory leaks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Leak pattern in NodeJS are mostly the same as known leak pattern for general JavaScript.

Just be careful with **Closure** and **Circular references** in Node. [Check this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Ok, but if I understand this article these memory leaks seem happen only when DOM objects are on the way. Nothing wrong when we are only using JS Objects, right?